# Nestjs custom CurrentUser decorator throw host.getArgByIndex is not a function

Tags: graphql, jwt, nestjs, nestjs-config

I am trying to implement login system using graphql in nest js.

I have login EP - works fine - returs Bearer token.

But I have `query` to get current user:

```
    import { CurrentUser } from '../auth/user.decorator'
.
.
.
    @Query()
    @UseGuards(JwtAuthGuard)
    public async me(@CurrentUser() user: any) {
        console.log(user)
        return { email: 'foo' }
    }
```

With custom decorator (`user.decorator.ts`):

```
import { createParamDecorator, ExecutionContext } from '@nestjs/common';
import { GqlExecutionContext } from '@nestjs/graphql';

export const CurrentUser = createParamDecorator(
  (data: unknown, context: ExecutionContext) => {
    const ctx = GqlExecutionContext.create(context);
    return ctx.getContext().req.user;
  },
);
```

When I run `me` I am getting an error `"host.getArgByIndex is not a function",` - it throw insinde `CurrentUser` decorator by `ctx.getContext()`... what is wrong?

Is my Import correct?

It it directly from nestjs doc:
https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/authentication

Comment: You are using Nest v7, correct? v6's `createParamDecorator` has a different signature

Answer (score 0):

You should check the version of Nest as Jay McDoniel's comment. If it is version 6, change the `createParamDecorator` to implement as the following

```js
import { createParamDecorator } from '@nestjs/common';

export const CurrentUser = createParamDecorator(
  (data, [root, args, ctx, info]) => ctx.req.user,
);
```